# Reporting tool for android app in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, report

I am developing an android application by using eclipse. I need the app to load data from sqlite database and generate a report and then export it to pdf format. Any good reporting tool can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

i use itext library for generating report in my own application. you must create all header section and content section of your report by yourself.